# Unable to pick a Value from Drop down

Tags: javascript, selenium, drop-down-menu, jasmine, protractor

I am unable to select Option from dropdown menu which has list value in it,

In the Catagory dropdown, I need to select T-Shirts and Youth and then Short Sleeve Option, Can someone help me with this?

I tried with following,

```
element(by.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-toggle']")).click();
element(by.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-toggle']")).sendKeys("Pants");
```

But it gives me an error as unable to find an element and it is not working.

Comment: The link address is so slow. please paste the html code here in order to help you

Comment: Hi @BzH Can i have ur mail id, i will send u, because here i couldnt paste the html code.

Comment: Link does not work... Update it with the correct one...

Comment: Yes @Grasshopper deployment happening, Will update just wait buddy

Comment: @Grasshopper@BzH Now the site is accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class name appliyed to target `div` is `' dropdown-toggle'`, not `'dropdown-toggle'`. Note the space character at the beggining. So you should use exact value as

```
element(by.xpath("//div[@class=' dropdown-toggle']")).click();
```

or ignoring spaces at the beggining and end

```
element(by.xpath("//div[normalize-space(@class)='dropdown-toggle']")).click();
```

Then you can use search by link text to select required option:

```
element(by.linkText("T-Shirts")).click();
element(by.linkText("Youth")).click();
element(by.linkText("Short Sleeve")).click();
```